# Calling member function of enclosing structure

Tags: c++, abstract-class, function-pointers

I have a situation where I have an instanced class that needs to call a function from the enclosing class. The top class is generated code and compiled after the bottom class is. A consequence is the top class name is not known by the bottom class.

```
class topClass
{
  public:
    void topFunction();
    bottomCLass * bcInst;
}

class bottomClass
{
  void * owner;
  void someFunction() {owner->topFunction(); }
}
```

Obviously this won't work since there's no definition for topClass.
How can I arrange this so the topClass function can be called from the bottomClass function? I tried using a parent class with a pure virtual function but this crashes when the function is called.

```
//This is defined and compiled with bottomClass
class classTemplate
{
  public:
    virtual void topFunction()=0;
}

class topClass : public classTemplate
{
  public:
    void topFunction();
    bottomClass * bcInst;
}

class bottomClass
{
  classTemplate * owner;
  void someFunction() {owner->topFunction();//Crashes here }
}
```

Is there a better way to solve this problem? The one thing I can't do is give bottom class the name/definition of top class, however the presence and name of topFunction is guaranteed.

Comment: have a look at this link http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.4 where he talks about virtual functions and how to define them in such was that the baseclass will call the derived version. not too sure if this is what you want though..

Comment: also, what do you mean "crashes". please specify what kind of crash we are talking about... the code you posted should be valid (with some minor issues) so could you eiter give more code or more crash report

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `someFunction()` implementation to `CPP` and include both headers in it. It will help you a lot:

topClass.h:

```
#ifndef TOPCLASS_H
#define TOPCLASS_H
#include "bottomClass.h"
class topClass
{
  public:
    void topFunction();
    bottomCLass * bcInst;
}
#endif
```

bottomClass.h:

```
#ifndef BOTTOMCLASS_H
#define BOTTOMCLASS_H
class bottomClass
{
  void * owner;
  void someFunction();
}
#endif
```

classes.cpp:

```
#include "topClass.h"
#include "bottomClass.h"

void bottomClass::someFunction() {owner->topFunction(); }`enter code here`
```

Comment: @Shahbaz: since OP didn't implement topFunction inside class declaration, I guess he already did this :)

Comment: So you're saying I can compile only bottomClass::someFunction in a different compilation unit. One that includes the definition for topClass and it's members.

Comment: @Adam12 yes, that's right. It will help you to avoid incomplete type errors.

Comment: This worked in my testcase, but unfortunately there are many topClasses so this results in multiple definition errors for the bottomClass::someFunction() declaration.

Comment: Include guards in your *.h files to avoid multiple declaration errors. Either use `#pragma once` or regular guards. I'll update my code.

Answer (score 0):

You could make `bottom` a template:

```
struct topclass
{
    void topfunction();
    bottom<topclass> * bcInst;
    // ...
};

template <typename T>
struct bottom
{
    T * p;
    void somefunction() { p->topfunction(); }
};
```

Whether that's feasible depends on whether the relevant template definitions are visible in the right places, and if you want the code duplication. You could just make the `bottom` template a small component inside an otherwise fixed, single "bottom" class in some sort of type-erasing scheme.

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to do something so simple with templates!

Comment: @Shahbaz maybe because it's possible? :)